# shift right/left (Bitwise Operators) in php7 gmp extension

Tags: php, gmp

[image]

What's the function name of `shift right/left` (Bitwise Operators) in php7 [gmp extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php)? No something like `gmp_shiftr` found.

Comment: phpseclib has a [version](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/master/phpseclib/Math/BigInteger/Engines/GMP.php#L385) that might help you

Answer (score 0):

[Notes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.gmp.php#99788) contributed by Nitrogen. May be helpful for someone else too.

```php
function gmp_shiftl($x,$n) { // shift left
  return(gmp_mul($x,gmp_pow(2,$n)));
}

function gmp_shiftr($x,$n) { // shift right
  return(gmp_div_q($x,gmp_pow(2,$n)));
}
```

> For those who wish to do bitwise shifting, it's quite simple.. to shift left, just multiply the number by pow(2,x), and to shift right, divide by pow(2,x).